# Project-specific print margin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

The print margin can be set by opening preferences and going to *General-->Editors-->Text Editors*. The default value there is 80 columns.

The 80-column value is fine for me but I'd like to override it for specific projects. Going to the properties of a project I found nothing related to it. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is only one preference value for this and it is global rather than per project.

See the preference page source `org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.TextEditorDefaultsPreferencePage`